# If $k > 1$, then $\frac1{(k - 1)^2}-\frac1{(k + 1)^2}=\frac{4k}{(k^2 - 1)^2}$, hence simplify $\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n\frac k{(k^2 - 1)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I have the following problem:

> Prove that if $k > 1$, then
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{(k - 1)^2} - \dfrac{1}{(k + 1)^2} = \dfrac{4k}{(k^2 - 1)^2}$$
>
> Hence simplify
>
> $$\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{k}{(k^2 - 1)^2}$$

**My Work:**

$$\dfrac{1}{(k - 1)^2} - \dfrac{1}{(k + 1)^2} = \dfrac{(k + 1)^2 - (k - 1)^2}{(k - 1)^2 (k + 1)^2} = \dfrac{(k + 1)^2 - (k - 1)^2}{(k^2 - 2k + 1)(k^2 + 2k + 1)}$$

I could have continued and multiplied the denominator out, but, at this point, I'm thinking that I'm actually expected to have proceeded differently, rather than multiplying the denominator out fully? And I don't have solutions for this problem, so I can't check anything.

I would appreciate it if someone could please take the time to explain this problem.

Comment: You already have $(k-1)^2(k+1)^2=(k^2-1)^2$ because $(k+1)(k-1)=k^2-1$. Just expand and simplify the numerator.

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles please.

Comment: @Did Sorry, I knew this but forgot this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some guidelines:

- Expand $(k+1)^2-(k-1)^2$, or use the rule $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.
- Notice that $(k-1)(k+1)=k^2-1$, thus $(k-1)^2(k+1)^2=?$
- Once you show that $$\dfrac{1}{(k - 1)^2} - \dfrac{1}{(k + 1)^2} = \dfrac{4k}{(k^2 - 1)^2},$$ you can use it so that the sum becomes\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=2}^n\dfrac{k}{(k^2-1)^2}&=\dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\dfrac{1}{(k-1)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)\\
  &=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\dfrac{1}{(k-1)^2}-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right);
  \end{align*}
  notice that by changing the variable $k-1$ into $k$, you get $$\sum_{k=2}^n\dfrac{1}{(k-1)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}.$$ Do the same for $\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$ and see what you'll get.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You factored out $\dfrac{1}{4}$ instead of $4$? If I am not mistaken, we also get $\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n \dfrac{1}{(k + 1)^2} = \sum\limits_{k = 3}^{n + 1} \dfrac{1}{k^2}$. So what do we do with $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k^2} + \sum\limits_{k = 3}^{n + 1} \dfrac{1}{k^2}$? I'm thinking that there's some simplification formula for $\sum \dfrac{1}{k^2}$ that I'm forgetting?

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes well $\dfrac{1}{(k - 1)^2} - \dfrac{1}{(k + 1)^2} = \dfrac{4k}{(k^2 - 1)^2}$ implies $\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{(k - 1)^2} - \dfrac{1}{(k + 1)^2}\right) = \dfrac{k}{(k^2 - 1)^2}$. Yes you're not mistaken (except for a $+$ instead of a $-$) you indeed get $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}-\sum_{k=3}^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}$. Now you see that you have a difference of sums which consists of the same terms, except that they differ at where they start and where they finish. So, many terms will cancel out!

Comment: Try to figure it out on your own. To help you, do it symbolically: write down $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k-\sum_{k=3}^{n+1}$ for small values of $n$, and see what you'll get. Notice that $a_3,a_4,\dots,a_{n-1}$ are in both sums, so they'll cancel out ;)

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks for that. So we are only left with the $k = 1$ and $k = 2$ terms from $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}$, and the $n$th and $(n + 1)$th terms from $\sum_{k=3}^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}$. So all of the terms cancel except for $\left( \dfrac{1}{1} + \dfrac{1}{4} \right) - \left( \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \dfrac{1}{(n + 1)^2} \right)$?

Comment: You got it! That's right!

Comment: great! Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is right.$$\text{Numerator}=(k+1)^2-(k-1)^2=k^2+2k+1-(k^2-2k+1)=4k\\\text{Denominator}=(k+1)^2(k-1)^2=(k^2-1)^2$$For the second part use telescopic rule. Can you finish now?

Comment: But how do we know that $(k+1)^2(k-1)^2=(k^2-1)^2$?

Comment: Why not? We know that $a^2b^2=(ab)^2$. Substitute $a=k+1$ and $b=k-1$ and use the identity $(k+1)(k-1)=k^2-1$

Comment: Oh, ok; that makes sense.

Comment: Good luck!.....